# Install Python 3.9 in Mendel on Google Coral Devboard

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os

Is it possible to upgrade from Python 3.7 to 3.9 on a Coral Dev Board?

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar Python en Coral Dev Board.

sudo apt-get install wget build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev -y

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/Python-3.12.2.tgz

tar xzf Python-3.12.2.tgz

cd Python-3.12.2 && ./configure --enable-optimizations

sudo make install

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.12 1

Verificar versión de python

python -V

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.12 1

Verificar versión de pip

pip -V